# Sort a combobox data in a formular

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

What can I change so it will work. I have 10 combobox they are depended of a value in a tabel called Rangetabel. In forms When I drop down the combobox I would like the tabel value to be sorted in a specific order, what did I do wrong?

```
' Update Accessories_1
q = "SELECT [Id],[Accessories 1],[Accessories 1 - SKU],[Accessories 1 - option],[Accessories 1 - info] FROM [Accessories_1] WHERE [Accessories 1 - option] LIKE '*" & Me.Rangetabel_Label.Column(2) & "*'"
Me.Accessories1_Label.RowSource = q
Me.Accessories1_Label.Requery
Me.Accessories1_Label.Visible = True
Me.Accessories1_SKU.Visible = True
Me.OrderBy = Me.Accessories1_SKU
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

How do I do that?

I have search for suggestion on the internet, but the only thing I found was how I sort a table.
I can't use the last suggestion.

Comment: Why don't you use ORDER BY clause?

Comment: I tried it didn't help.

Comment: What exactly did you try? The SQL statement does not show ORDER BY clause. Edit your question. Maybe you should post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the combo box then in the property sheet, Row Source, add ORDER BY [your field name] at the end of your SQL. I think ASC is by default.  Did you put your field name that to be sorted?

Comment: Sorry vbakim i didn't work